# Kong wrong evaluation order with regex uris

Tags: kong

These are my kong apis:

```
{
   "total" : 5,
   "data" : [
      {
         "upstream_read_timeout" : 60000,
         "retries" : 5,
         "strip_uri" : false,
         "upstream_connect_timeout" : 60000,
         "created_at" : 1515179488893,
         "preserve_host" : false,
         "https_only" : false,
         "upstream_send_timeout" : 60000,
         "uris" : [
            "/users/\\d"
         ],
         "id" : "edbc93f2-e897-490f-a0a5-7fb627eb8748",
         "upstream_url" : "http://172.18.0.3:8002",
         "http_if_terminated" : false,
         "name" : "account"
      },
      {
         "upstream_send_timeout" : 60000,
         "id" : "2d76ec3e-df4d-43f1-8bbb-79e613f882a8",
         "uris" : [
            "/\\w"
         ],
         "upstream_url" : "http://172.18.0.3:8002",
         "http_if_terminated" : false,
         "name" : "login",
         "upstream_read_timeout" : 60000,
         "strip_uri" : false,
         "retries" : 5,
         "upstream_connect_timeout" : 60000,
         "created_at" : 1515179488936,
         "https_only" : false,
         "preserve_host" : false
      },
      {
         "name" : "event",
         "upstream_url" : "http://172.18.0.10:8004",
         "http_if_terminated" : false,
         "uris" : [
            "/users/\\d /calendars/\\d /events"
         ],
         "id" : "2f5c90de-dc09-43f3-92d4-7d798b6fd149",
         "upstream_send_timeout" : 60000,
         "preserve_host" : false,
         "https_only" : false,
         "retries" : 5,
         "strip_uri" : false,
         "upstream_connect_timeout" : 60000,
         "created_at" : 1515179488801,
         "upstream_read_timeout" : 60000
      },
      {
         "preserve_host" : false,
         "https_only" : false,
         "created_at" : 1515179488610,
         "retries" : 5,
         "strip_uri" : false,
         "upstream_connect_timeout" : 60000,
         "upstream_read_timeout" : 60000,
         "name" : "instructions",
         "http_if_terminated" : false,
         "upstream_url" : "http://172.18.0.13:8005",
         "uris" : [
            "/users/\\d /calendars/\\d /events/\\d /recurrence/\\d /instruction"
         ],
         "id" : "4e0462ff-3446-4f2a-9a54-d0e6fb385a2c",
         "upstream_send_timeout" : 60000
      },
      {
         "retries" : 5,
         "upstream_connect_timeout" : 60000,
         "strip_uri" : false,
         "created_at" : 1515179488849,
         "preserve_host" : false,
         "https_only" : false,
         "upstream_read_timeout" : 60000,
         "upstream_url" : "http://172.18.0.7:8003",
         "http_if_terminated" : false,
         "name" : "calendar",
         "upstream_send_timeout" : 60000,
         "uris" : [
            "/users/\\d /calendars"
         ],
         "id" : "1e12ba7e-571b-4d02-9e70-a6823db0606d"
      }
   ]
}
```

which are created with these commands:

```
# instructions
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
    -d 'name=instructions' \
        -d 'upstream_url=http://172.18.0.13:8005' \
        -d 'uris=/users/\d+/calendars/\d+/events/\d+/recurrence/\d+/instruction' \
    -d 'strip_uri=false'
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/instructions/plugins --data "name=jwt"
# event
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
    -d 'name=event' \
        -d 'upstream_url=http://172.18.0.10:8004' \
        -d 'uris=/users/\d+/calendars/\d+/events' \
    -d 'strip_uri=false'
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/event/plugins --data "name=jwt"
# calendar
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
    -d 'name=calendar' \
        -d 'upstream_url=http://172.18.0.7:8003' \
        -d 'uris=/users/\d+/calendars' \
    -d 'strip_uri=false'
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/calendar/plugins --data "name=jwt"
# account
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
    -d 'name=account' \
        -d 'upstream_url=http://172.18.0.3:8002' \
        -d 'uris=/users/\d+' \
    -d 'strip_uri=false'
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/account/plugins --data "name=jwt"
# login
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
    -d 'name=login' \
        -d 'upstream_url=http://172.18.0.3:8002' \
        -d 'uris=/\w/' \
    -d 'strip_uri=false'
```

If I try to access the `/users/3/calendars`, I get redirected to the `account` api (defined with `uris=/users/\d+`), but I'm expecting instead to be redirected to the `calendar` api (defined with `uris=/users/\d+/calendars`). From the [docs](https://getkong.org/docs/0.11.x/proxy/#evaluation-order):

> As previously mentioned, Kong evaluates prefix URIs by length: the longest prefix URIs are evaluated first. However, **Kong will evaluate regex URIs based on the order in which they are defined.**

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the `curl` command, in order to use `+` in the request when setting the uris `--data-urlencode` needs to be used instead of `-d`